# Grouping various rows using exceljs for angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, export-to-excel, exceljs

I have been using exceljs to create excel files and downloading them. I have currently run into the problem of grouping them something like this: [Click here for grouping example](https://www.google.com/search?q=grouping+rows+in+excel&rlz=1C5GCEA_enUS868US871&sxsrf=ALeKk01EWKiGpLdC_JnRH5JqfyL_QIXZSA:1595364845828&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUsrCXnd_qAhXGFjQIHQugDqkQ_AUoAnoECA0QBA&biw=1680&bih=922#imgrc=wyKeVvcOb-vEkM)

Is there any way of doing this using exceljs? I have tried doing
something like

```
worksheet.addRows([['Hello'],['Hello']]);
```

but that just puts them one above another and does not group them.

Answer (score 0):

In excel groups of rows named "Outlines". In documentation of ExcelJS on github i found this https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#outline-levels

Groups make by set value to the attribute "outlineLevel" for rows or cols.